# jQuery parent element event 'click' blocks a href links

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

When setting up a div with a class, attaching a `click` event to that class using jQuery, it prevents any child href from working.
For example:

HTML

```
<div class="someClass">
    some text here 
    <a href="http://www.google.com">and a link</a>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('body').on('click', '.someClass', function(e) {
    alert("clicked");
});
```

jsfiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/w6ero5j5/2/

it will always alert the message, even when clicking on the link.
how can I make the link works?

Comment: hacky fix: wrap the alert in: `if (e.target.nodeName != 'A') { alert(...); }`

Comment: This code is working fine, the problem is you are running it at jsfiddle and it won't load the link inside the jsfiffle' area (take a lok at the browser inspector, it throws an error). Add target="_blank" to the href and it will work.

Comment: The problem is that the load of Google inside jsfiddle is denied by X-Frame-Options, because Google does not permit cross-origin framing.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why do you want this. But, it happen when you put alert function.
Then If you execute this, there is not problem. [code here](http://jsfiddle.net/w6ero5j5/2/)

```
$('.someClass').on('click', function(){
  var $this = $(this);
    if ( $this.hasClass("ok") ) {
      $this.removeClass("ok");
    } else {
      $this.addClass("ok");
    }
});
```